# fluentui/react-nortstar Menu how to provide space between content and wrapper

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

how do we override the styles and provide the space between the content and wrapper,
[image: as show in the attachment]

tried to add styles

```
const myTheme: ThemeInput = {
   componentStyles: {
    Menu: {
      root: {
        color: "yellow",
        //tried to provide maring space but it is taking for whole menu, rather menuitem content 
      },
    }
  }
 };
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on space between "content and wrapper"?
Please share some screenshot with highlights in it?

Comment: https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.60.1/components/menu/definition
in the provide link we have menu with Underlined 
i want to make look like the above image i have attached

Comment: Do you want to remove the underline or want to increase the space? Could you please try as below:
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
export default class MyLabel extends Component {
  render() {
    return <label className={this.props.className}>{this.props.children}</label>;
  }
}
const StyledMyLabel = styled(MyLabel)`
    color: green;
`;

Comment: i want to increase the space

Comment: You can use custom css for this. You need to override below class by inspecting  `<span class="ui-menu__itemcontent of og oh oi bz gx" dir="auto">Editorials</span` as follow: `.oi {
margin-bottom: 0.7143rem;
}`. However it is not the ideal way to do so.

Comment: thanks you, it works, i would like to know, if any standard way of doing it apart from this

Comment: No there doesn't seem to be any other way

Answer (score 0):

I did the following. There is still some slight jumping which I think is coming from the `MenuItemWrapper`. You could play around with the numbers and see if you can get the desired size. The docs are really not clear and I don't know if this approach will be removed in later versions.

```js
<Menu underlined primary defaultActiveIndex={0} styles={{ border: 0 }}
    items={[
        {
            key: "itemOne",
            content: "ItemOne",
            styles: ({ props }) => {
                return {
                    paddingBottom: 5,
                    marginBottom: props.active ? 0 : 5,
                    ":hover": {
                        marginBottom: 0,
                        paddingBottom: 5
                    }
                };
            }
        },
        // ...other items 
    ]}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom css for this. You need to override below class by inspecting

`<span class="ui-menu__itemcontent of og oh oi bz gx" dir="auto">Editorials</span`

as follow:

```
 .oi {
     margin-bottom: 0.7143rem;
   }
```

.

Comment: the issue is resolved, thanks for you help